# how to make a second counter

Tags: java, counter

I'm trying to make a second counter using a do-while loop, that stops when the user's input equals q. But I have no idea about how to make the counter counting seconds, this is my code:

```
public class Search {
    static public void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int seconds = 0;
        System.out.println("Insert q to stop:");
        char i;
        i = (char) System.in.read();
do {
    seconds++;  
    
} while(i != 'q');
    }
}
```

And the output is this one:

```
Insert q to stop:
q
1
```

Comment: The question isn't just clear what you want

Comment: That output is not from that code.

Answer (score 2):

Following line should be within the loop.

```
i = (char) System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how much time passed you can use `System.currentMillis()`. Instead of putting a counter for seconds.

```java
long startTime = System.currentMillis();
//... your code

long endTime = System.currentMillis();
long timePassed = endTime - startTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to get the time in seconds till q is entered then the following code will do that

```
public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char i;
        do {
            System.out.print("Insert q to stop:");
            String str = sc.next();
            i = str.charAt(0);
        } while (i != 'q');
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double executionTime = (endTime - startTime) / 1000d;
        System.out.println(executionTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `second` varibale to keep track of time from when the program started till the time user inputs `q`.

I'll suggest instead of declaring `seconds` as `local` declare it in  `global`.

```
public class Search {
int seconds = 0;    // changed 
static public void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Insert q to stop:");
        char i;
        i = (char) System.in.read();
do {
    seconds++;  
} while(i != 'q');
    }
}
```

And if u want to read the whether `q` is input or not you can do:

```
public class Search {
    static public void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int seconds = 0;
        System.out.println("Insert q to stop:");
        char i;   
do {
    i = (char) System.in.read(); // changed
    seconds++;  
    
} while(i != 'q');
    }
}
```

Because when `i = (char) System.in.read()` is out of `do-while` it will only read once and will be an infinite loop if `q` wasn't the input.